# Using WHERE for partial field match - How

Tags: sql, field, match, partial

Hello this is my first post and I am fairly new to SQL. Really what I am trying to find is an equivilent to MID$ where I can make updates based on part of a field.

```
    UPDATE OurTable
 SET UpdateField='Text-2008-001-old'
  WHERE '2008' like ('%' || UpdateField) AND KeyField='1'
```

In other words I wand to update to 'Text-2008-001-old' where the field might currently be 'Line-2008-000-000'

The position of the 2008 does not change within the existing data so really I just need to update and fields that contain 2008 where the KeyField is '1'

If there is a good online resource for SQL syntax that I have not found yet please feel free to point me there.

Hope I have explained this OK and thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use LIKE:

```
UPDATE OurTable
SET UpdateField='Text-2008-001-old'
WHERE UpdateField LIKE '%2008%' AND KeyField='1'
```

Or if there are always dashes around it, perhaps `LIKE '%-2008-%'` would be better.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked perfectly for my needs.

[code]
WHERE UpdateField LIKE '%2008%' AND KeyField='1'
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE OurTable
 SET UpdateField='Text-2008-001-old'
  WHERE UpdateField like 'Line-2008%' AND KeyField='1'

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of wildcards to use with the LIKE operator (%,_,[],[^], etc.) -- explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx.

There is also the substring() function -- explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx, that is kind of like a MID function in other languages.  (WHERE...LIKE SUBSTRING(...))

Comment: sorry -- that is all for TSQL btw -- not sure what dialect you're interested in.